# Not getting values of radiobutton using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to set values of checked `radiobutton` in a variable. But I am unable to get it. Below is the code what I tried

```js
master.controller('FiberLead_Filter', function($scope, $http, NEIQC_Service, Scopes, $rootScope) {
      var rdSelectMP = $scope.MPSelect; // here I am getting undefined
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="rightFilter" ng-controller="FiberLead_Filter as Filter" id="FiberLead_Filter">
  <div class="pdfDownload customeRadioWrap">
    <div class="customeRadio">
      <input type="radio" id="btnCurrentMP" name="radio-group" ng-model="MPSelect" ng-value="Current">
      <label for="btnCurrentMP">Current MP</label>
    </div>
    <div class="customeRadio">
      <input type="radio" id="btnAllMP" name="radio-group" ng-model="MPSelect" ng-value="All">
      <label for="btnAllMP">All MP</label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default customBtn" ng-click="DownloadExcelReport()"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know what is wrong with my code as I am getting it `UNDEFINED`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `ng-value` is looking for the "All" `$scope` variable, but there likely is none.
If the expected value is a string, either use `'All'` or, instead, just use `value`.

Working fiddle below, click the "download" button to log the current value (select a value first).

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('FiberLead_Filter', function($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
      $scope.DownloadExcelReport = function(){
        console.log($scope.MPSelect);
      }
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="rightFilter" ng-controller="FiberLead_Filter as Filter" id="FiberLead_Filter">
    <div class="pdfDownload customeRadioWrap">
      <div class="customeRadio">
        <input type="radio" id="btnCurrentMP" name="radio-group" ng-model="MPSelect" value="Current">
        <label for="btnCurrentMP">Current MP</label>
      </div>
      <div class="customeRadio">
        <input type="radio" id="btnAllMP" name="radio-group" ng-model="MPSelect" value="All">
        <label for="btnAllMP">All MP</label>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-default customBtn" ng-click="DownloadExcelReport()"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect mate, it worked.I was just missing the value attirbute I guess. I was thinking of doing something like `ng-click` and get the current value

Comment: it's just that ng-value, like ng-click, takes an expression. In that case, ng-value looks for `$scope` property, so it won't work as expected if you simply need to bind a string.